# Como realizar um "IF" por SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá, como posso fazer algo semelhante a um if mas por sql?
Por exemplo: Existe um campo no banco de dados chamado **dt_ini** com nenhum valor até agora.
Eu gostaria de fazer: "Se **dt_ini** == **' '** insert into tabela (**dt_ini**) values ..."
Teria que fazer uma consulta no banco de dados para ver o **dt_ini** é ou tem o valor nulo, se sim insert into... senão ...

Comment: Já tentou fazer um `insert-select`?

Comment: não entendi direito o proposito, mas a condicional é feita pelo case when: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: If no SQL? Desculpe se eu estiver falando besteira, mas um Where não te atende?

Comment: Where... bem pensado, acredito que me atende sim

Answer (score -1):

Opa MrVanDaime, tenta fazer o seguinte,

INSERT INTO ***SUA_TABELA*** (dt_ini) VALUES ***VALOR*** WHERE DT_INI IS NULL;

OU

INSERT INTO ***SUA_TABELA*** (dt_ini) VALUES ***VALOR*** WHERE DT_INI = "";

Comment: Essa sintaxe é válida no `MySQL`? Só vi no máximo `insert-select` com cláusula `where`

Comment: Creio que não: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query

Answer (score -1):

Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer atualizar o valor do dt_ini da própria tabela? caso esteja vazio?

Se for isso, tente isso:

```
UPDATE SUA_TABELA SET DT_INI = VALOR WHERE DT_INI IS NULL
```

Se for um insert em outro lugar, caso o dt_ini esteja vazio, tente:

```
INSERT INTO SUA_TABELA (CAMPOS) VALUES (VALORES) WHERE 1 IN (SELECT 1 FROM SUA_TABELA WHERE DT_INI IS NULL)
```

Comment: Você testou esse INSERT? Nunca vi essa sintaxe e nem encontrei na documentação.]

Comment: Sim, já usei algumas vezes. Na documentação você vai encontrar falando sobre o IN comparando com outra select. Neste caso, se a select trouxer resultado, este será o disparador do insert.